# VBA PowerPoint Display and Hide Shapes

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have several PowerPoint slides with objects (arrows and rectangles) I like to display and hide. At the moment I just use

```
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide100").Shapes("Rectangle 99").Visible = False or True

ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide100").Shapes("Straight Arrow Connector 118").Visible = False or True
```

Now it can be that one rectangle or arrow has to be deleted in that template. This leads to VBA errors when you run the macro because the rectangle or arrow couldn't be found. Is there any way to write a macro to check all the used rectangles and arrows and then hides or displays them all instead of using single variables?

I found something like this:

```
For Each sObject In ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Shapes
sObject.Visible = False
Next
```

But I just need to hide rectangles and arrows, nothing more.

Best regards
Peter

Answer (score 4):

Take that loop as a starting point and apply some logic within it. There are two properties of the shape that could be useful, `autoshapetype` and `name`

Two examples below:

```
For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes
    If InStr(1, shp.Name, "Rectangle") > 0 Then
        shp.Visible = False
    End If
Next shp
```

or

```
For Each shp In ActivePresentation.Slides(x).Shapes
    If shp.AutoShapeType = msoShapeRectangle Then
        shp.Visible = False
    End If
Next shp
```

Answer (score 2):

This will hide all rectangle types and a subset of arrow types across all slides in the active presentation:

```
' PowerPoint VBA Macro
' Purpose : hide rectangles and shapes across slides
' Written by : Jamie Garroch of YOUpresent Ltd. http://youpresent.co.uk.
Sub HideRectanglesAndArrows()
  Dim oSld As Slide
  Dim oShp As Shape
  For Each oSld In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oShp In oSld.Shapes
      If oShp.Type = msoAutoShape Then
        Select Case oShp.AutoShapeType
          ' Basic Arrows (4)
          Case msoShapeUpArrow, msoShapeDownArrow, msoShapeLeftArrow, msoShapeRightArrow
            oShp.Visible = msoFalse
          ' Double Arrows (2)
          Case msoShapeUpDownArrow, msoShapeLeftRightArrow
            oShp.Visible = msoFalse
          ' Add other arrow types as required
          '
          ' Basic Rectangles (1)
          Case msoShapeRectangle
            oShp.Visible = msoFalse
          ' Rounded Rectangles (4)
          Case msoShapeRound1Rectangle, msoShapeRound2DiagRectangle, msoShapeRound2SameRectangle, msoShapeRoundedRectangle
            oShp.Visible = msoFalse
          ' Snipped Rectangles (4)
          Case msoShapeSnip1Rectangle, msoShapeSnip2DiagRectangle, msoShapeSnip2SameRectangle, msoShapeSnipRoundRectangle
            oShp.Visible = msoFalse
        End Select
      End If
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

You can then add logic to delete specific shapes using the .Name property or position properties (.Left, .Top) or size properties (.Width, .Height). If you want o be more elaborate (users can change the names of shapes) then you could add Tags to shapes to identify them in a way that the user cannot change and then write a procedure to check the .Tags property in your logic.