# VBA Powerpoint: Can i hide shapes randomly on a slide?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, hide, maven-shade-plugin

you can use VBA to hide shapes: [VBA PowerPoint Display and Hide Shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890885/vba-powerpoint-display-and-hide-shapes)

But can you hide shapes randomly on a slide (all but one specific)?

I don´t know how to make a random on a

```
ActivePresentation.Slides("Slide1").Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible = False
```

I aspect, that i can hide a random shape on the actual slide by click(the Shape must have to be a visible shape before, so that another start of the code does hide randomly the next visible shape and not the hidden shape again).

Comment: You can make an array of existing shapes, then generate a random number within the range of the number of shapes, then hide the array shape that matches the random number. Then you would create another array of only the visible shapes and repeat the process, so the first shape hidden remains hidden.

Comment: Thank you. But if i do so i will always hide the one shade, which i don´t want to hide. Or i would have to create the array manually every time i have hidden a shade from the array.

Comment: Do you mean "shade" or "shape"? 

You'll have explain what you're trying to do more clearly to get better help.

Comment: Thx, shape. Sry. I have a picture and many shapes over the picture - hiding it. This shapes hiding the picture shuold be randomly hidden/sent to background/ deleted. On 1 mouseklick 1 shape should be deleted randomly. But never the picture which is below the shapes.

Comment: I'm getting the impression you're expecting someone here to write the macro for you. That's not the purpose of Stack Overflow. Here is Microsoft's page on the Randomize function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement